# Sed/awk: Aligning words in a file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, text-processing

I have a file with the following structure:

```
# #################################################################
#   TEXT: MORE TEXT
#   TEXT: MORE TEXT
# #################################################################

___________________________________________________________________
ITEM 1
___________________________________________________________________
PROPERTY1:     VALUE1_1
PROPERTY222:   VALUE2_1
PROPERTY33:    VALUE3_1
PROPERTY4444:  VALUE4_1
PROPERTY55:    VALUE5_1

Description1:  Some text goes here
Description2:  Some text goes here

___________________________________________________________________
ITEM 2
___________________________________________________________________
PROPERTY1:     VALUE1_2
PROPERTY222:   VALUE2_2
PROPERTY33:    VALUE3_2
PROPERTY4444:  VALUE4_2
PROPERTY55:    VALUE5_2

Description1:  Some text goes here
Description2:  Some text goes here
```

I want to add another item to the file, using sed or awk:

```
 sed -i -r "\$a$PROPERTY1:     VALUE1_3" file.txt
 sed -i -r "\$a$PROPERTY2222:     VALUE2_3" file.txt
```

etc. So my next item looks like this:

```
___________________________________________________________________
ITEM 3
___________________________________________________________________
PROPERTY1:     VALUE1_3
PROPERTY222:     VALUE2_3
PROPERTY33:     VALUE3_3
PROPERTY4444:     VALUE4_3
PROPERTY55:     VALUE5_3

Description1:  Some text goes here
Description2:  Some text goes here
```

The column *values* is jagged. How do I align my values to the left like for previous items? I can see 2 solutions here:

1. To align the values while inserting them into the file.
2. To insert the values into the file the way I did it and align them next.

The command

```
sed -i -r "s|.*:.*|&|g" file.txt
```

catches the properties and values I want to align, but I haven't been able to align them properly, i.e.

```
awk '/^.*:.*$/{ printf "%-40s %-70s\n", $1, $2 }' file.txt
```

It prints out the file, but it includes the description values and tags, cuts the values if they include spaces or dashes. It just a big mess.

I've tried more commands based on what I've found on Stack Overflow and some blogs, but nothing does what I need.

Note: Values of the description tags are not jagged- this is because I write them to the file in a separate way.

What is wrong with my commands? How do I achieve what I need?

Comment: While this is solvable using sed/awk, it might be easier to solve with mightier tools. Have you considered using a full-fledged programming language (e.g. perl, ruby, c++) with proper data structures to solve your problem?

Comment: @Heinrich, I'd like to avoid using full-fledged programming languages, because I have an almost complete script in bash that does exactly what I want and this is the only problem with it. I don't want to force the users of my script to install compilers or interpreters for different languages due to this (not so serious) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your file is without tabs, try this:

```
sed -r 's/: +/:\t/' file.txt | expand -20
```

When this works, redirect the output to a tmpfile and move the tmpfile to `file.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gensub and thoughtful field seperators to take care of this:

```
for i in {1..5}; do
    echo $(( 10 ** i )): $i;
done | awk -F ':::' '/^[^:]+:.+/{
    $0 = gensub(/: +/, ":::", $0 );
    key=( $1 ":" );
    printf "%-40s %s\n", key, $2;
}'
```

The relevant part being where we swap out ": +" for just ":::" and then do a printf to bring it back together.

Comment: You're calling gensub() incorrectly (you're populating the "how many replacements" field with `$0`), you don't need parens around string concatenation, you don't need trailing newlines, I can't imagine what changing `: +` to `:::` and setting FS to `:::` is supposed to do instead of just setting FS to `: +` (who's to say `:::` doesn't exist in a VALUE?) or just using a couple of sub()s. Oh, and you should mention it's gawk-specific due to use of `gensub()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use \t to insert tabs (rather than spaces which is why you get 'jagged' values)

instead of

```
sed -i -r "\$a$PROPERTY1:     VALUE1_3" file.txt
```

use

```
sed -i -r "\$a$PROPERTY1:\t\tVALUE1_3" file.txt
```

Comment: Using tabs might still result in jagged alignment, when one key's length is e.g. two tabs (plus some spaces) long and another key is three tabs (again, plus some spaces) long.

Comment: @M.B. It doesn't matter if I am inserting tabs or spaces.Names of the properties differ in length, so I'm always going to get jagged values.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remember the existing indentation when inserting the new line, e.g.:

```
echo 'PROPERTY732:    VALUE9_8_7' |
awk -v prop="PROPERTY1" -v val="VALUE1_3" '
        match($0,/^PROPERTY[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/) { wid=RLENGTH }
        { print }
        END { printf "%-*s%s\n", wid, prop":", val }
    '
PROPERTY732:    VALUE9_8_7
PROPERTY1:      VALUE1_3
```

but it's not clear that adding 1 line at a time makes sense or where all of the other text you're adding is coming from.

The above will work with any awk on any UNIX system.

If your "properties" don't actually start with the word PROPERTY then you just need to edit your question to show more realistic sample input/output and tell/show us how to distinguish a PROPERTY line from a Description line and, again, the solution will be trivial with awk.